# JS sum of 2 numbers return a bad result

Tags: javascript

I calculate a lot of number with javascript. In some calculation i have a bad result.

Exemple: http://jsfiddle.net/6et8d10c/

```
var num1 = 2.01;
var num2 = 22.29;
var result = num1 + num2; //24.29 (should be 24.30)
```

For now I fix with:
(2.01*100 + 22.29*100) / 100 = 24.30

That's not perfect. Why can't i calculate 2.01 + 22.29 ?

Comment: js has floating calculation issue. what you have done that is the right way to resolve this pblm,

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)